# ios: falling photos animation

Tags: ios, animation, 3d

I'm developing an ordinary iPad application on one of the screens of which there should be the following.

Here is the background image http://postimage.org/image/pmykiudut/

This is a box without a cover and there is a slit. Photos (I have them) should realistically fall from that slit on the floor.

I have implemented some simple animation which uses `[UIView animateWithDuartion...]` but that's not the best solution, becuse the photos are always behave themselves as firm rectangles with this approach.

I have tried to add perspective and rotation with Core Animation framework and `layer.transform` property, but the result was worse than in the previous case...

Photos are considered to be paper. They should be light and flexible.

There are some videos showing how it should look like:

- Cutting phase
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6O5us2-uvXU
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeDGrB8s0Uo#t=217s
- Falling phase
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIK9F5v0iZc

Please, direct me, what is the best way to make photos flexible and move them such a complex way? Which framework should I choose? Or are there something resembling implemented somewhere? Where to look and where to dig? )

I've started to learn cocos2d, but I'm not sure if there are such an ability there...

Comment: You're going to want to use Core Animation to animate the pictures. It's quite powerful once you learn it.

Comment: Yes, and I wanted! But it can't make a picture look flexible. Any transform it provides is made on a rectangular layer, and at the output the layer always remains straight. It does not bend, curve or curl. I think, it's impossible with Core Animation.